# How to fix this multiple definition of functions linking issue in kernel modules

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, kernel-module

During my first kernel porting project I am facing this linking issue , anyone familar with ?

linux/arch/arm/mach-xxx$ vi hotplug.c +110

```
110 int platform_cpu_kill(unsigned int cpu)
111 {
112         return 1;
113 }
```

During compiationI am getting this multiple definition of error ?

```
arch/arm/mach-xxx/built-in.o: In function `platform_cpu_kill': arch/arm/mach-xxx/hotplug.c:111: multiple definition of `platform_cpu_kill' arch/arm/mach-xxx/built-in.o:arch/arm/mach-tyranno/hotplug.c:111: first defined here arch/arm/mach-xxx/built-in.o
```

platform_cpu_kill() only has single definition , There are not any other definition or declaration in header , still it throws multiple definition of platform_cpu_kill

```
   arch/arm/mach-xxx$ grep -inr "platform_cpu_kill"
        hotplug.c:110:int platform_cpu_kill(unsigned int cpu)
        Binary file hotplug.o matches
        Binary file built-in.o matches
```

arch/arm/mach-xxx$ cat Makefile

```
obj-y += common.o io.o

obj-$(CONFIG_SMP) += platsmp.o headsmp.o
obj-$(CONFIG_PM) += pm.o hotplug.o
obj-$(CONFIG_SUSPEND) += sleep.o
obj-$(CONFIG_HIBERNATION) += hibernate.o hibernate_asm.o
```

Comment: Maybe you linked both hotplug.o and built-in.o?

Comment: What kernel version do you build? What is `mach-xxx`? Is it the directory created by you (so every file in it is created by you too)? Or is this a specific subdirectory of `arch/arm`? The "multiple definition" error means, that the function is defined somewhere else, not necessary under `arch/arm/mach-xxx` where you run `grep`.

Comment: Go to the root of source tree and run the following `git grep -n -w platform_cpu_kill`. What is the output? (And avoid using `grep` in Git trees, it's not effective, @Tsyvarev, JFYI)

Comment: Thanks @0andriy , making static fix that issue , but I got similar error for other functions

Comment: Make them all static, it’s a good practice anyway.